# Magento 1.9.0.1 to 2.0.2. migration tool integrity check failed

Tags: magento2, ce-1.9.0.1, magento2-migration-tool, magento-2.0.2

I'm trying to use the magento 2 data migration tool, but i keep getting errors when i try to start data migration.

I've looked around for people who also get the integrity check failed notice, but their error seem diffrent and their solution don't work for me.

I'd be great if someone can point me in the right direction to solving this issue!

See below a screenshot for the command i executed en the output with errors. I added -vvv because someone on another forum/topic suggested it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding a  rule for all the tabled/fields that came up in the error log.